# Yolov5 custom dataset :dataset.yaml file issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov5

1)Is it necessary to clone the Yolov5 git repo in the same drive and folder where we save our train/test images?
2)I have cloned the yolov5 git repo in C drive [C/yol5/yolov5] and my train/test images are in E drive under img_data folder
(Train= E/img_data/train   Test= E/img_data/test)
Here, how should I specify the path in dataset.yaml for train:  and test:

P.S :I’m using anaconda prompt for running the training command for yolov5

Answer (score 2):

1. No, but you must address the location of each file. For instance:

```
!python /path/to/yolo/yolov5/train.py --img 800 --batch 14 --epochs 50 --data /path/to/defects.yaml --cfg /path/to/yolo/yolov5/models/yolov5x.yaml --weights yolov5x.pt --name whatever --cache
```

2. Same as 1